# Any thoughts/ideas on what mighty be stopping 'align-tems:center;' from providing an output?

Tags: html, css

This might be a dumb question but align items, did not work for me but it has been for my entire time writing code. I don't know why the output is not aligning the text inside of my div. Just looking for a little help, even if it is a dumb simple answer.

here is the code:

html:

```
        <div data-aos="fade-in" class="head">
            <p class="head-text">Top Artists and Songs of 2023<p>
        </div>
```

css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #212121;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.head {
    background-color: #111111;
    color: #1d8954;
    filter: brightness(150%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    margin:0;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.head-text {
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin:0;
}
```

sorry for the long css tab, just wanted to add everything in case something obscure in the beginning might have changed the output.

Heres the output (the negative output is with the green text not aligning to the center on the vertical axis):

[the problem is it's not vertically centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgdHa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss `display: flex`?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #212121;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.head {
    background-color: #111111;
    color: #1d8954;
    filter: brightness(150%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.head-text {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div data-aos="fade-in" class="head">
  <p class="head-text">Top Artists and Songs of 2023<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you so much! I honestly knew it was gonna be something dumb that i forgot.